# Func<> delegate - Clarification

Tags: c#, delegates, c#-2.0, func

When an array is given:

```
int[] a={1,3,4,5,67,8,899,56,12,33}
```

and if i wish to return the even numbers using LINQ

```
var q=a.where(p=>p%2==0)
```

If i were to use C#2.0 and strictly func<> delegate what is the way to solve it?

I tried :

```
Func<int, bool> func = delegate(int val) { return val % 2 == 0; };
```

but I am confused how to link the array "a" here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int[] q = Array.FindAll<int>(a, delegate(int p) { return p % 2 == 0; });
```

(note this uses `Predicate<int>`, which is the same signature as `Func<int,bool>`)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Predicate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) and [`Array.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd.aspx).

```
Predicate<int> func = delegate(int val) { return val % 2 == 0; };

Array.FindAll<int>(a, func);
```